# Target element outside onclick event?

Tags: html, css, onclick, toggle

I'm doing a page for someone. I toggled the visibility of a div with a checkbox however, he wants to change the height of the header which comes before the content div which has the onclick event. Could anyone help me out? either css or js/jquery.

What I want:
checkbox off: div hidden & header height 412px.
checkbox checked: div showed & header height 212px.

```css
header {
width:100%;
height:412px;
text-align:center;
background:#1f1f1f;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
position:relative;
}
#wrapper td {
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
}
#wrapper td img {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: 736px;
height: 105px;
margin-top: -52px; /* Half the height */
margin-left: -368px; /* Half the width */
}

div.content { 
  background:#ebebec;
  position:relative;
  top:100px;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: BlueHighway, Arial Black, sans-serif;
  top:0;
}
div.content label {
  display: block;
  width:80px;
  height:88px;
  background:url(http://i.imgur.com/Buvp49A.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-bottom:30px;
}
div.content label:hover { 
  cursor: pointer; background-position: center bottom; 
}
div.button {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  top:-67px;
  padding-top:22px;
  background:url(http://i.imgur.com/Gf3QAxt.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
}
input.toggle ~ div.description { 
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .6s all cubic-bezier(0.730, -0.485, 0.145, 1.620)
}
input.toggle:checked ~ div.description { height: 530px; }
input.toggle:checked + label { background-position: center bottom; }
input.toggle { display: none; }
```

```html
<header>
<table id="wrapper">
<tr>
<td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vE3KBOv.png" alt="Santos@imvu"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</header>
<div class="content">
  <div class="button">
<input type="checkbox" id="punch" class="toggle">
  <label for="punch"></label>
  <div class="description">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8sY0E5c.gif" style="max-width:100%;height:auto" alt="bla">
  </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/CvanLiere/pen/WvqXBv)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

I've set the initial height to `212px` and added a new class to CSS `header.expand` where you set the height to `412px`. After that you trigger the `click()` event for the checkbox in jQuery and toggle the `expand` class with `toggleClass(...)`

**SNIPPET**

```js
$('#punch').click(function() {
  $('header').toggleClass('expand');
});
```

```css
html {
  background: grey;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #ebebec;
  width: 926px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  color: grey;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 212px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #1f1f1f;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: height .8s ease-out;
}
header.expand {
  height: 412px;
}
#wrapper td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
#wrapper td img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 736px;
  height: 105px;
  margin-top: -52px;
  /* Half the height */
  margin-left: -368px;
  /* Half the width */
}
.image {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 94px;
}
footer {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #1f1f1f;
  margin-top: 28px;
  color: #fff;
  clear: both;
}
a {
  color: #0082ff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
p {
  width: 870px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
div.content {
  background: #ebebec;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: BlueHighway, Arial Black, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
}
div.content label {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 88px;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/Buvp49A.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
div.content label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-position: center bottom;
}
div.button {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -67px;
  padding-top: 22px;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/Gf3QAxt.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
}
input.toggle ~ div.description {
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .6s all cubic-bezier(0.730, -0.485, 0.145, 1.620)
}
input.toggle:checked ~ div.description {
  height: 530px;
}
input.toggle:checked + label {
  background-position: center bottom;
}
input.toggle {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <table id="wrapper">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vE3KBOv.png" alt="Santos@imvu" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</header>
<div class="content">
  <div class="button">
    <input type="checkbox" id="punch" class="toggle">
    <label for="punch"></label>
    <div class="description">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8sY0E5c.gif" style="max-width:100%;height:auto" alt="bla">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes but the other way around, it has to shrink when clicking the button. but i will change the class name & height. Thank you so much c:

Comment: Oops, my bad. Yeah, I've to be more patient while reading the questions.
You're welcome! ;)

Comment: Aparently the page only accepts html & css is there a css only option? if not i will tell him it's not possible unfortunately :/

Comment: I don't think that you can manipulate other elements through checkbox by using CSS, except they are siblings. (If they are it's possible to use adjacent sibling combinator)